# Circular AngularGauge does not roll over boundaries

Tags: graphics, gui-construction

I am using the Mma9 `AngularGauge` function to develop a controll for a rotating stage.  I am experiencing several problems:

1. I am unable to get the values {0°, 90°, 180°, 270°}.
2. I am unable to align those values at arbitrary locations, e.g. 0° at the top.
3. I cannot make the needle roll over the 0° / 360° boundary, i.e. to
   get from 10° to 350° I have to "roll back".

In particular the function `ScaleDivisions` drives me nuts.  In the figure below the 0 in 360 is drawn twice, not clearly visible here but obvious on my screen.  I am not concerned about the "°" right now and my Mma9 installed without any error messages (unitil now).

`AngularGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 360}, ScaleDivisions -> {20, 2},
 ScaleOrigin -> {0, 2 \[Pi]}, ImageSize -> {256, 256}, 
 GaugeLabels -> "Value", GaugeMarkers -> "InsideScale"]`

[image]

Comment: I guess internally `FindDivisions` is being used which has the (documented) habit of yielding the number of divisions that it thinks looks best. This often approaches, but does not equal, the number the user specified.

Comment: Is the 0 being drawn twice because it's showing both 0 and 360 in the same place?

Comment: @cormullion yes, changing `{0,360}` into `{0,359.9}` does not draw `360` while still letting you select it (although `x` is not updated to be 360, it is only gets to 359.9 but shows as 360 in the gauge)

Comment: I guess that the developers' intent was that users would set the range to `[0, 350}` for gauges like this one. I suspect they did not intend to support roll over. I think they are mimicking physical gauges which don't roll over in my experience.

Comment: The 'ClockGauge' appears to be a normal 'AngularGauge' but with different labels and roll over. If that is true, there must be some functionality to add the roll over.

Comment: A magnetic compass is also a physical gauge and would certainly roll over.

Comment: @ cormullion Yes, that is the reason.  I would like to see the 0, 20, ... and 340.

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, but personally I would just draw it from scratch... My comment is mainly caused by indignation about having the `System` context bloated by such unnecessary functions.

Answer (score 1):

For #2, you can adjust `ScaleOrigin` to set start/end angle to be wherever you like say you want `0` at angle $\theta$ use `ScaleOrigin->{\[Theta]-2\[Pi],\[Theta]}` or interchange the order to have the gauge increase in the other direction.

```
AngularGauge[Dynamic[x], {0, 360}, ScaleDivisions -> {20, 2}, 
 ScaleOrigin -> {Pi/2, (-3 Pi)/2}, ImageSize -> {256, 256}, 
 GaugeLabels -> "Value", GaugeMarkers -> "InsideScale"]
```

[image]

Note that the 360 and 0 in the same place really makes the gauge look broken now that 0 is drawn over the 6 making it look like 300 instead

Comment: Trust me, I tried all the obvious stuff and I am aware of the the ScaleOrigin option.  I want to see 90° at the top.  In your response 360 and 0 are also printed on top of each other.

Comment: @ErnstStelzer yes I was clear this was just for second problem, with `ScaleOrigin->{-2Pi,0}` I have 90 at the top.

Comment: @Ernst your question clearly states "e.g. 0° at the top." -- please try to be consistent.